# appending new line with sed command in bash

Tags: bash, sed, text-processing

Hi I have trouble appending newline by sed command. I was instructed to write a command that update host file. Also, My sed command is written in bash script, though it kept outputting error message. It said "sed: -e expression #1, char 93: extra character after command."

this is the contend I want to add to my hosts file.

```
# Gateway
10.0.0.1    schoolhost  it20
# Addresses for the Windows
10.0.0.240  host1 it21
10.0.0.241  host2 it22
```

This is the command I wrote in bash script.

```
sed -i "/hosts/a \
\n# Gateway \
\n10.0.0.1    schoolhost  it20 \
\n# Addresses for the Windows PCs \
\n10.0.0.240  host1 it21 \
\n10.0.0.241  host2 it22" hosts
```

Comment: Do you just need to append those exact lines to the hosts file?

Comment: yes, even the coment. The orginal content of the host file only have "localhost". this script suppose to update it. It's more like a backup script.

Comment: Upload your file somewhere and post the link.

Comment: https://ufile.io/9l5d4 for the host_update. https://ufile.io/5hn8pfor the host file

Comment: You have created or edited the file with a Windows system.

Comment: No, i copied from a remote server which is running g Ubuntu.

Comment: My bad, there are spaces after "\" symbol, silly me. it works now. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given:

```
$ cat file
line 1
line 2
line 3
```

And:

```
$ echo "$add_this"
# Gateway
10.0.0.1    schoolhost  it20
# Addresses for the Windows
10.0.0.240  host1 it21
10.0.0.241  host2 it22
```

You can do several things to add those text elements together.

The first is to use `cat` (recalling the name comes from con**cat**tenate):

```
$ cat file <(echo "$add_this")
line 1
line 2
line 3
# Gateway
10.0.0.1    schoolhost  it20
# Addresses for the Windows
10.0.0.240  host1 it21
10.0.0.241  host2 it22
```

Or, you can use `awk` the same way:

```
$ awk '1' file <(echo "$add_this")
# same output
```

Or, an empty `sed`:

```
$ sed -e '' file <(echo "$add_this") 
# same output
```

Or with `printf`:

```
$ printf "%s%s\n" "$(cat file)" "$add_this"
# same output
```

Bottom line is you are only adding two pieces of text together and there are many ways in Unix to do that.

Then redirect the output of any of those (likely `cat`) to a temp file then move the temp file onto the source file:

```
$ cat file <(echo "$add_this") >/tmp/tmp_file && mv /tmp/tmp_file file
$ cat file
line 1
line 2
line 3
# Gateway
10.0.0.1    schoolhost  it20
# Addresses for the Windows
10.0.0.240  host1 it21
10.0.0.241  host2 it22
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a need for `sed` here. Just use `cat` and a here document.

```
cat <<EOF >> hosts
# Gateway
10.0.0.1    schoolhost  it20
# Addresses for the Windows
10.0.0.240  host1 it21
10.0.0.241  host2 it22
EOF
```